# Google Adsense Account Disapproved: Insufficient content, but want to ad adsense to another website

Tags: google-adsense

I had earlier applied for an adsense account for a domain, but it was disapproved because there was not sufficient content on it. However, now I don't want to adsense on that domain. Instead I have another domain on which I want to use adsense. But when I login into the adsense, it asks me to just resubmit the old request, and not allow to change the site url. Is there any way I request the old request and request for a new site account?

Answer (score 1):

Either contact AdSense support or register using a new email address

Answer (score 1):

It might take a long time to get a reply from adsense support. Instead just try to add more content to your original website, even if you don't want adsense there. You only need it to get the approval. Immediately after you get the approval, you can restore the old site to its original condition and put adsense on your new site.

Comment: Great way to get banned from AdSense

Comment: No, it's not. Please show me the policy which tells that you must use AdSense which you used to get the approval.

Comment: `"You only need it to get the approval. Immediately after you get the approval, you can restore the old site to its original condition and put adsense on your new site."` What you're suggesting is to show the AdSense team some content to get approved and after approval switch the content, that's against their TOS. https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23921&topic=1271503&ctx=topic `Google will take action against domains that don’t add any value to users.`

Comment: Still don't see the problem here. If the domain is approved, that means it satisfied all policies at the time of approval. After that, there won't be any adsense on the domain so it doesn't have to follow any adsense policies.